# Excel Producing Cumulative Frequency Graph From Timestamps and Frequency

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have competition on google forms, and once a form is submitted the data is sent to a new row in an excel spreadsheet, including a timestamp column `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss`. What I need to now do is plot a cumulative frequency graph that has time along the bottom, and the cumulative amount of form submissions on the y-axis. So let's say I get 100 submissions and the majority happen in the beginning, middle and end of the competition, it should look like this: https://ibb.co/m37u9v (I can't post an image because I don't have 10 rep)

I would like it to be automated, so update the graph as soon as a new entry is submitted.

Sorry I am a complete newbie to excel so as much detail would help in your answers.

Thanks, Adam :)

Comment: what is the total duration of the competition? I think if it is like more than a few days, the time information that you have as a part of the timestamp will not be useful. It is better to get rid of that and get that to `mm/dd/yyy` format . Would it be right to do that?

Comment: The competition is a week so I guess remove minutes and seconds but keep hours

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed the input data without the hours, minutes, seconds for the sake of simplicity. However, you can extract the timestamp and play with it as you may like.

Below is a snapshot of the input data, how it should be processed and how the graph is drawn.

[image]

I will upload this file to [google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-6XDkJiElCbdmVGMWc4aHVXY3M) for reference.

Comment below if you have specific questions